# how to load iframe concurrently using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how can i load load iframe concurently using javascript or jquery?
Example :I have iframe[0], iframe[1], iframe[2], iframe[3], how to load them concurrently?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Set their `src` attribute:

```
$("iframe").each(function () {
  $(this).attr("src", ...);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The usage of jQuery is all fine, but its possible with pure JS too, even IE8 supports it. ;)

```
el.setAttribute('attribute', value);
```

In your case, it would be:

```
el.setAttribute('src', 'the/path/to/whatever');
```

Comment: This was meant as a placeholder for the attribute you want to alter.^^ I will add a more specified line of code to show the proper usage.